# Count rows from another table referencing current row by foreign key

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have tables as follows:

```
inverter [ id, address, ... ]
string [ id, inverter_id (foreign key), ... ]
```

I want to select all "inverters", together with the number of "strings" attached to them.

I tried this query here, but it gives me empty result, so how can I do this?

```
SELECT inverter.*, COUNT(string.*) as string_count
FROM inverter 
LEFT JOIN string ON string.inverter_id = inverter.id
ORDER BY address
```

I am using SQLite3.

---

Here's a dump of the test tables I have now:

```
CREATE TABLE `inverter` (`id` INTEGER NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `address` VARCHAR(3) NULL, `comment` VARCHAR(250) NULL);

INSERT INTO "inverter" ("id","address","comment") VALUES ('2','A1','North side');
INSERT INTO "inverter" ("id","address","comment") VALUES ('3','A2','Broken inverter');
INSERT INTO "inverter" ("id","address","comment") VALUES ('4','A3','');
INSERT INTO "inverter" ("id","address","comment") VALUES ('5','A4','South-west corner');


CREATE TABLE `string` (`id` INTEGER NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `address` VARCHAR(3) NULL, `inverter_id` INTEGER NULL, `comment` VARCHAR(250) NULL, FOREIGN KEY (`inverter_id`) REFERENCES `inverters` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL);

INSERT INTO "string" ("id","address","inverter_id","comment") VALUES ('1','XX','3','');
INSERT INTO "string" ("id","address","inverter_id","comment") VALUES ('2','XY','3','Ahoj jak se máš');
INSERT INTO "string" ("id","address","inverter_id","comment") VALUES ('3','XZ','4','Moo');
```

Comment: Really empty? This should return one row.

Comment: Yeah it gives nothing. I've now added a dump so please look if I have anything wrong there maybe...?

Comment: This query has multiple syntax errors (COUNT cannot use table aliases; the column name in ORDER BY is ambiguous). Show the query that you are actually using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems SQLite3 chokes on `count(s.*)` so try this instead:

```
select i.*, count(s.id) 
from inverter i 
left join string s on i.id = s.inverter_id group by i.address;
```

This gives:

```
2|A1|North side|0
3|A2|Broken inverter|2
4|A3||1
5|A4|South-west corner|0
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I believe sqlite somehow confused the same-named columns in the two tables, could that be it?

Comment: @MightyPork I don't think it confuses the columns, but rather that you can't do the `count(table.*)` but I could be wrong; I'm not that familiar with SQLIte specifics.

Comment: yeah that part causes error too, but there was more. anyway thanks for this, it runs nicely now :)

Answer (score 0):

Using an aggregate always means that you are grouping, and if you don't specify the grouping it will be a single group containing all records. Group on the fields that you get from the `inverter` table. Also use a single field in the count instead of `string.*`:

```
select
  inverter.id, inverter.address, count(string.id) as string_count
from
  inverter 
  left join string on string.inverter_id = inverter.id
group by
  inverter.id, inverter.address
order by
  inverter.address
```

Comment: This still gives me zero rows, any clue what's wrong?

Comment: It appears to work after you address the `string.*` by naming one column on the table: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/1b216/8/0 (updated w/ group by)

Answer (score -2):

Change the table name "string". That is a reserved word.

Comment: No, it's not a reserved word.